# why is latex making my caption bold?

Tags: latex, bold, captions

I don't know why latex is making my captions bold.

```
\section*{附录}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
{
   \label{fig:ILOVEYOU}
   \includegraphics[scale=2.7]{ILOVEYOU.jpg}
}
\caption{ILOVEYOU蠕虫邮件}
\end{figure}
```

I added a figure with a caption earlier and it wasn't bolded.
Thank you!

Comment: Hm, I see no particular reason it should be bold. (Is the entire text bold or just the "Fig. 1.1:" bit?)

Unrelatedly, \label needs to go after \caption and I'd drop the braces: \centering is a switch and not a command.

Secondly, you might have more luck asking on tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: You need to give a complete example - something before this code is the problem.

Comment: the entire thing is bold, starting from "Fig"

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to get around it. All I did was add some text after the section and before the first figure. If there isn't text, everything is bold. I realized this later when I noticed that not only the caption was bold but so was the footer.
I don't know why it's like this or how to fix it, but adding a few explanatory sentences before my figures works for me.